# Why does my initramfs not detect init

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I am compiling an initramfs from minimalfs and it fails to detect init during boot.
I have 2 simlinks one at /init and another at sbin/init both pointing to /sbin/init.sysvinit

I just have tried passing the filesystem directory as well as the cpio in the kernel config. The following is the tail of bootlog:

=========================================================

```
[    2.152221] vmmc: supplied by vbat                                           
[    2.157139] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz                  
[    2.165445] omap_i2c 4802a000.i2c: bus 1 rev0.11 at 100 kHz                  
[    2.208472]  remoteproc0: wkup_m3 is available                               
[    2.213169]  remoteproc0: Note: remoteproc is still under development and co.
[    2.222618]  remoteproc0: THE BINARY FORMAT IS NOT YET FINALIZED, and backwa.
[    2.233660]  remoteproc0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2          
[    2.240280]  remoteproc0: Falling back to user helper                        
[    2.245995] cpu cpu0: of_pm_voltdm_notifier_register: Fail calculating volta2
[    2.259066] input: volume_keys.8 as /devices/volume_keys.8/input/input2      
[    2.266959] /home/preetam/Workspace/neato/ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-)
[    2.287394] Warning: unable to open an initial console.                      
[    2.300184] Freeing unused kernel memory: 4212K (c0587000 - c09a4000)        
[    2.307330] Failed to execute /init (error -2)                               
[    2.312502] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing .
[    8.180642] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

==========================================================================

The following is my bootargs:

"console=${console} earlyprintk=serial mem=128m"

The hardware I am using is am335x based custom board which is a full custom version of beagle bone that is product specific. Has 128MB DDR ram.

Comment: -2 is ENOENT. Have you tried chrooting into your initramfs directory and running init to verify that the file has all its dependencies met?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you please explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: It appears to be a "file not found" error. You need to provide all the files needed to run your init, which includes 1. the symlink, 2. its target, 3. the target's interpreter if any, 4. the dynamic linker for the target or its interpreter. You can check if you have everything without rebooting by using your initramfs as your root fs with `chroot` and executing your init.

Comment: I removed a lot of libraries and /bin and /sbin commads assuming that they might not be used. How do I find out the dependency of init ?

Comment: It uses init.sysvinit which is not a dynamic executable. ldd says "not a dynamic executable".

Comment: `ldd` will say this if the file is a dynamic executable for a different platform, which from your edit appears to be the case. `file` will more accurately determine whether it's dynamically linked

Comment: You are right, file says
ELF32 LSB executable, ARM EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BUildID[sha1]=.....,stripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init was an elf binary with dynamic libraries linked to it. I found it by using readelf -d on the init file. So I needed to add the libc library that I thought would be linked statically in init.
Big thanks to "that toher guy".

Comment: I would like to improve the answer by mentioning that -2 in your case is ENOENT.